# Is there a cartoon character to be used in blender similar to fuse

Tags: rendering, rigging

Good day. I'm new to blender animation.

I'm a software developer who is trying to create animation to upload on youtube to have an extra income.

I starting learning animation using after effects and rigging using DUIK. I'm not an artist and i can't draw so i use images from freepik.com but i encountered problems. Like i need to rotate the character which i can't do it in after effects because of the 2d images. Then i found out blender which use 3d character which is mostly all of my problems are solved.

But the last problem i have is the characters.

I found out about FUSE but the characters are too realistic.

Is there a character creator that the output is similar to this which is cartoon character

https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/free-obj-model-ivysaur-pokemon-sample/1136333

And to be able to use in blender

Comment: Artell, the creator of the Auto Rig Pro addon, has made a character named Mike, which was made with the addon, available for free. You don't need the addon to use the rig. You only need it to make one like it. He's kind of cartoony. http://www.lucky3d.fr/auto-rig-pro/mike.zip

You might consider getting the addon itself if you want to use Blender to make characters.

Comment: @R-800 thank you. I'll check it out.